# Proof the set of all non-negative vectors is closed

Tags: general-topology

Let $S$ be the set of all vectors in $R^n$ with non-negative entries.
I know that $S$ is a closed set in $R^n$, but how does one prove this formally?

Comment: Typically, you take a convergent sequence of such vectors, show from the norm that the specific coordinates are also convergent sequences in the interval $[0, \infty)$. Since that interval is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that $S$ is closed too.

Comment: typically use assume closure as an axiom of the vector space. In your case you have to interpret $\mathbb{R}^n$ to have less structure.

Comment: @user48672 Your comment makes little to no sense.

Comment: @user48672: Judging by the tags, I'm assuming the OP meant closed topologically, not closed algebraically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by assuming you have a sequence $(x_m)_{m=1}^\infty \in S$ that converges to some $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We must show that $x \in S$. I don't know what definition you're using, but you should know that proving this is equivalent to showing $S$ is closed.

Let $x^i_m$ be the $i$th coordinate of $x_m$. As per the hints you've received, we need to show $x^i_m \to x^i$, the $i$th coordinate of $x$. We can show this easily by squeeze theorem. Since $x_m \to x$, we have $\|x_m - x\| \to 0$, hence
$$0 \le |x^i_m - x^i| = \sqrt{(x^i_m - x^i)^2} \le \sqrt{(x^1_m - x^1)^2 + \ldots + (x^n_m - x^n)^2} = \|x_m - x\| \to 0.$$
Now, $x^i_m \ge 0$, so the limit $x^i \ge 0$, since the interval $[0, \infty)$ is closed, hence $S$ is closed.

(To show $[0, \infty)$ is closed, take a sequence $a_n \to a$, where $a_n \ge 0$. Show using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ arguments that $a > -\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon > 0$, and then that this can only be the case if $a \ge 0$.)

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Your set is $\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^n \pi_i^{-1}\big([0,\infty)\big)$, where $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are the projections in the $i$-th coordinate. Since the projections are continuous, $[0,\infty)$ is closed and intersection of closed sets is closed, it follows that your set is closed.

Comment: Does one need to show that $\pi^{-1}$ exists? Or it is evident by construction?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;\{x_m\}_{m=1}^\infty\subset S\subset\Bbb R^n\;$ such that $\;\lim\limits_{m\to\infty} x_m\;$ exists (finitely). This means each coordinate sequence's limit exists finitely (I'm assuming here Euclidean topology).

Now answer: can the limit of a converging sequence of non-negative real numbers converge to a *negative* number?

Comment: I understand your method, and obviously the answer to your question is no, but then how do I go about proving it formally?

Comment: @YuvalNissan This should be elementary calculus: (1) a non-negative sequence can **not** converge to a negative value (with epsilon and $\;N\in\Bbb N\;$ and etc.),  and  (2) a sequence of vectors in $\;\Bbb R^n\;4 converges iff each and every coordinate sequence converges.

Answer (score 1):

$S = [0,\infty)^n$ is a product of closed spaces, hence closed.